# How do you calculate per capita?

Tags: probability, ratio

The Population of the U.S. 318,000,000

The following is a break down of food stamp usage by race...

```
RACE A: 35% | 63.7% of US population
RACE B: 22% | 12.2% of US population
RACE C: 10% | 16.3% of US population
RACE D:  2% |  4.7% of US population
RACE E:  4% |  0.7% of US population
RACE U: 19% |  0.2% of US population
(source: 2014 U.S. Department of Agriculture, U.S. Census)
```

(the first number is participation in food stamp program as a percentage of the total population)

I tried to get the total number of food stamp recipients times the percent for each race and the total population for each race then divide them to get the per capita value for each race.

The total number of recipients represented 19.7% of 318M US population.

```
318000000*0.197 = 62646000
---------------------------------------
21926100/202566000 = 10824.2 per 100000
13782120/38796000  = 35524.6 per 100000
6264600/51834000   = 12085.9 per 100000
1252920/14946000   = 8383.0  per 100000
2505840/2226000    = 112571  per 100000
11902740/63600000  = 18715   per 100000
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Number of hospital beds in town $= 431$

population in town$= 390,000$

divide number of beds by population then multiply $\times 1000$

$431/390,000\cdot1000= 1.1$ beds per $1000$ people.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take raw data. Note that `2.2%` of US population is not mentioned.

```
Participiants/Race population | Race population/US population
                   White: 35% | 63.7%
        African American: 22% | 12.2%
                Hispanic: 10% | 16.3%
                   Asian:  2% |  4.7%
         American Indian:  4% |  0.7%
                 Unknown: 19% |  0.2%
                               ======
                                97.8%
```

Then, get the number `Participiants/US population` for each race:

```
  Participiants/US population = First column * Second column
                   White: 22.295%
        African American:  2.684%
                Hispanic:  1.630%
                   Asian:  0.094%
                 Unknown:  0.038%  
         American Indian:  0.028%
                          =======
                          26.769%
```

That gives you an overall frequency (according to your data): `26.769%`.